# Trying to create a CSS-only popout effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover panel effect which will pop out to the left but I'm having a few troubles with it. I've attached an image of the effect I'm trying to make.

[image]

There is an example of what I'm trying to make over on CodePen. Check it out:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CgKqs

I must be having a total mental block today because I simply cannot figure this out. My aim is to do this without javascript, as a CSS-only thing. **I'm having real trouble getting the 'pop out' to position correctly.**

**Specific issues are:**

1. After hovering (returning to it's supposed default state) items disappear in IE.
2. The hovered 'pop out' forces a horizontal scrollbar to appear.

Can some kind and ninja-like HTML/CSS genius lend a hand?

Thanks,

Adam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```css
/* Galerie */
.galerie { float:right; height:440px; width:160px; padding:10px; 
           background-color:grey; }

/* Content boxes here */
.cont { float:right; height:130px; width:150px; padding:4px; margin-top:4px; 
background-color:grey;  border:1px solid #000; border-radius:16px 16px 16px 16px; }

/* Dont display the text until hover */
.txt { float:left; width:53%; display:none; }

/* There is 4px padding between img and content div so for a fitting look 
   radius of image should be 16 - 4 = 12px */    
.pic { float:right; display:block; }
.pic img { height:130px; width:150px; border-radius:12px 12px 12px 12px; }

/* On Hover */
.cont:hover { width:320px; background-color:white; }
.cont:hover .txt { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="galerie">
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="pic"><img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/140095/140095,1310613638,1/stock-photo-team-work-ants-constructing-bridge-80955316.jpg"></div>
        <div class="txt">
            This is the text of content
            and some more text to see
            and a little more text..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="pic"><img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/51333/51333,1199715661,1/stock-photo-young-puppy-listening-to-music-on-headphones-8323504.jpg"></div>
        <div class="txt">
            This is the text of content
            and some more text to see
            and a little more text..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="pic"><img src="http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/57421/57421,1154123042,1/stock-photo-four-penguins-in-antarctica-1607229.jpg"></div>
        <div class="txt">
            This is the text of content
            and some more text to see
            and a little more text..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit: new fiddle link added..

https://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/sd8mLajr/

you can turn those content divs into links if you want.

Comment: Hi Berker. That's the solution I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This magic is generally done using hover attribute to a CSS style.

You define two styles, one is for normal and another is for hover. When the user hovers over a particular object, the hover one will automatically come in effect

like this

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

You can apply as much attributes you want on hover.

This is also known as pseudo class.

have a look at this link

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Hi Murtuza, it's getting the thing to display correctly when you hover over an item, especially in terms of float/position. If you look at the CodePen I made you'll see the specific issue I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

The code you put on codepen does not work because you need `display: block` on you `a` element for the `hover` pseudo class to work:

```
.thingie li a {
  display: block;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest.
First without hover let the extra content be clipped, by reducing width and useing

```
overflow:hidden
```

On css hover increase the width to show the complete box or  show the overflowed content
for example

```
yourSelector{
   width:200px;
   overflow:hiddden;
}

yourSelecto:hover{
   overflow:visible;
   width:400px 
}
```

Choose the width and rest of styling carefully to achieve this effect. I used to create scroll down menus this way, when I hadn't learned javascript.